# Object downloaded from firebase do not behave normally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a situation like this :
I want to output an array of React components based on a firebase database request.

```
class component exends React.component {
  constructor () {
    ...

    firebase.database().ref( '/properties/' ).once( 'value' ).then(
      snapshot =>
        {
          var obj = snapshoot.val();

          arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj )
                  .map( key => { name: obj[key].name, ... } );

          this.setState( { elements : arr } );
        }
      );

   ...
  }

  ...

  render () {
    return(
      <Container>
        {this.state.elements.map(el => <Element {...el} />)};
      </Container>
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

At runtime, I find that the `<Container>` component has an extra element. However, when I check the size of the array just before the render function, the size is correct.

I know that the problem comes from the firebase database request because when I replace the data by order data that do not come from the firebase database everything behaves correctly.

The most astonishing is that if build the array inside the firebase request function callback without using any data providing from the firebase database the same problem arise again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I fact the extra element was added by a lower level `SizeMe` component. I don't know why the problem only occurs with the firebase objects, However, when I wrap the content of the `SizeMe` component with a `<div>` I got rid of the extra element at the start of the array.